# how to write bash script to filter some data in logs

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, cut

I have a log file in this format.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
name=abc
address=country:US,Zip:12345/1,city:ny/1,state:ny/1, yearsLived:5/1,other details
healthDetails=healthplan:medixx/1, expensesInDollars:150/1, other details
-----------------------------------------------------------

name=xyz
address=country:US,Zip:12345/1,city:ny/1,state:ny/1, yearsLived:3/1,other details
healthDetails=healthplan:medixx/1, expensesInDollars:150/1, other details
-----------------------------------------------------------

name=awd
address=country:US,Zip:12345/1,city:ny/1,state:ny/1, yearsLived:2/1,other details
healthDetails=healthplan:medixx/1, expensesInDollars:150/1, other details
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the name of the person and years lived if years lived are greater than certain years(say 2) for each name in the log file. The file will have duplicate names too with different details.

Output:

```
name:abc
yearLived:5
name:xyz
yearsLived: 3
```

I was trying to use the grep and cut commands to do that. The problem I am facing is that once I do grep or cut I lose the other part i.e. either name or address. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Don't use `grep` or `cut`. Use `awk` or similar tools.

Comment: What is /1 after every value in this? And is log always in this format,i.e. A new line after name line?

Comment: that is just some version number related to logs(ignore that). and yes the format is always the same

Comment: @EtanReisner : How does awk help here? Doesn't awk also work in a similar way? could you provide an example?

Comment: Show a small (but bigger :) sample of your log file with some names you want and some you don't, and then show the exact output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jas updated the question. though I have kept the information almost same apart from name and years

Comment: awk helps because you can do more than just blindly match and cut text with it. You have arbitrarily complex logic and fancier ways to break data into records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a stab at it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "name="} NR > 1 {match($0, "yearsLived:[0-9]+", yl) ; split(yl[0], years, ":")} NR > 1 && years[2] > 2 {print $1 "\t" years[2]}' records_file
```

Edit:  Accommodating the updated log line sample and desired output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = "-{59}"} NR > 1 {match($0, "yearsLived:[0-9]+", yl) ; split(yl[0], years, ":")} NR > 1 && years[2] > 2 {sub("=", ":", $1); print $1 "\n" yl[0]}' records
```

Edit 2:  Oops, meant to add a comment:  To change the threshold for matching the number of years, change the second `2` in `years[2] > 2`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: could you explain why you used -59 here. I removed that and tried with your first comment and it worked.

Comment: I'm setting a record separator.  Awk typically uses newlines to indicate a new record, but your file appears to use a series of 59 hyphens to separate them; hence, `-{59}`.  In the first one, I wasn't sure (until you provided a little more data to play with) whether the hyphens were really in the data or were just for convenience on SO.  So, I used `name=` as the separator.  Once it was clear that the hyphens were really in the data, it became much easier to just use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

using awk like

```
awk '$0~/^name/{split($0,a,"=")}{if($0~/yearsLived:[3-9]/){split($0,b,":|/");print "name:",a[2] "\nyearsLived: "b[9]}}' 'my_file'
```

To break the one line shell code down

create a text file named `awkscript` and add the following code

```
#!/bin/awk
$0~/^name/{
    #find all lines that has name and reference in using an array 'a'   
    split($0,a,"=") 
          }
#find all lines that has years lived >2 and print name and years lived
{if($0~/yearsLived:[3-9]/){ 
    split($0,b,":|/");print "name:",a[2] "\nyearsLived: "b[9] #print name and year
}
}
```

Now run awk script in your shell like

```
 awk -f 'awkscript'  'my_file'
```

Comment: Thanks Xorg. I was initially getting all the years lived in a file first then grepping it in the original logs to get the names and everything. This makes it much easier.